# pure javascript to disable all form elements inside div

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to disable all fields (textarea/textfield/option/input/checkbox/submit etc) in a form by telling only the parent div name using pure javascript and not jquery or angular?

I want pure javascript because I am just getting started with JS and I find all the different permutations quite confusing.

---

I am currently doing something like, but would like streamline this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    ( document.onclick = function() {
      var clickNoElements = [ 'juniperPresentNo', 'customerJuniperPresentNo', 'mpr95001PresentNo', 'mpr95001PresentNo', 'noranTelPresentNo', 'powerPlantPresentNo', 'batteryRackCabinetPresentNo', 'bbu1PresentNo', 'siteAlarmMdfPresentNo', 'towerLightsPresentNo', 'generatorPresentNo', 'tlanPresentNo' ];

      var clickYesElements = [ 'juniperPresentYes', 'customerJuniperPresentYes', 'mpr95001PresentYes', 'mpr95001PresentYes', 'noranTelPresentYes', 'powerPlantPresentYes', 'batteryRackCabinetPresentYes', 'bbu1PresentYes', 'siteAlarmMdfPresentYes', 'towerLightsPresentYes', 'generatorPresentYes', 'tlanPresentYes' ];

      var disableEnableElements = [ 'buttonJuniperChecks', 'juniperChecksOk', 'juniperChecksNok', 'buttonBellCeJuniperChecks', 'customerJuniperChecksOk', 'bellCeJuniperChecksNok', 'buttonMpr95001Checks', 'mpr95001ChecksOk', 'mpr95001ChecksNok', 'buttonMpr95001Checks', 'mpr95001ChecksOk', 'mpr95001ChecksNok', 'buttonNoranTelChecks', 'noranTelChecksOk', 'noranTelChecksNok', 'buttonPowerPlantChecks', 'powerPlantChecksOk', 'powerPlantChecksNok', 'buttonBatteryRackCabinetChecks', 'batteryRackCabinetChecksOk', 'batteryRackCabinetChecksNok', 'buttonBbu1Checks', 'bbu1ChecksOk', 'bbu1ChecksNok', 'buttonSiteAlarmMdfChecks', 'siteAlarmMdfChecksOk', 'siteAlarmMdfChecksNok', 'buttonTowerLightsChecks', 'towerLightsChecksOk', 'towerLightsChecksNok', 'buttonGeneratorChecks', 'generatorChecksOk', 'generatorChecksNok', 'buttonTlanChecks', 'tlanPresentChecksOk', 'tlanPresentChecksNok' ];
    })();

    function mobilityJuniperPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'mobilityJuniperPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonMobilityJuniperChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'mobilityJuniperChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'mobilityJuniperChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonMobilityJuniperChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'mobilityJuniperChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'mobilityJuniperChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      mobilityJuniperPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "mobilityJuniperPresent" ]' ).on( "click", mobilityJuniperPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function customerJuniperPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'customerJuniperPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonCustomerJuniperChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'customerJuniperChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'customerJuniperChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonCustomerJuniperChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'customerbellceJuniperChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'customerJuniperChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      customerJuniperPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "customerJuniperPresent" ]' ).on( "click", customerJuniperPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function mpr95001Present() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'mpr95001PresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonMpr95001Checks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'mpr95001ChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'mpr95001ChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonMpr95001Checks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'mpr95001ChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'mpr95001ChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      mpr95001Present(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "mpr95001Present" ]' ).on( "click", mpr95001Present );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function mpr95002Present() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'mpr95002PresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonMpr95002Checks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'mpr95002ChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'mpr95002ChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonMpr95002Checks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'mpr95002ChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'mpr95002ChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      mpr95002Present(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "mpr95002Present" ]' ).on( "click", mpr95002Present );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function noranTelPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'noranTelPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonNoranTelChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'noranTelChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'noranTelChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonNoranTelChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'noranTelChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'noranTelChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      noranTelPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "noranTelPresent" ]' ).on( "click", noranTelPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function powerPlantPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'powerPlantPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonPowerPlantChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'powerPlantChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'powerPlantChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonPowerPlantChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'powerPlantChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'powerPlantChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      powerPlantPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "powerPlantPresent" ]' ).on( "click", powerPlantPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function batteryRackCabinetPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'batteryRackCabinetPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonBatteryRackCabinetChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'batteryRackCabinetChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'batteryRackCabinetChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonBatteryRackCabinetChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'batteryRackCabinetChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'batteryRackCabinetChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      batteryRackCabinetPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "batteryRackCabinetPresent" ]' ).on( "click", batteryRackCabinetPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function bbu1Present() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'bbu1PresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonBbu1Checks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu1ChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu1ChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonBbu1Checks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu1ChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu1ChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      bbu1Present(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "bbu1Present" ]' ).on( "click", bbu1Present );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function bbu2Present() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'bbu2PresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonBbu2Checks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu2ChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu2ChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonBbu2Checks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu2ChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu2ChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      bbu2Present(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "bbu2Present" ]' ).on( "click", bbu2Present );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function bbu3Present() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'bbu3PresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonBbu3Checks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu3ChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu3ChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonBbu3Checks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu3ChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'bbu3ChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      bbu3Present(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "bbu3Present" ]' ).on( "click", bbu3Present );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function mdfPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'mdfPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonSiteAlarmMdfChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'siteAlarmMdfChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'siteAlarmMdfChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonSiteAlarmMdfChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'siteAlarmMdfChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'siteAlarmMdfChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      mdfPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "mdfPresent" ]' ).on( "click", mdfPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function towerLightsPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'towerLightsPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonTowerLightsChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'towerLightsChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'towerLightsChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonTowerLightsChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'towerLightsChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'towerLightsChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      towerLightsPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "towerLightsPresent" ]' ).on( "click", towerLightsPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function generatorPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'generatorPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonGeneratorChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'generatorChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'generatorChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonGeneratorChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'generatorChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'generatorChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      generatorPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "generatorPresent" ]' ).on( "click", generatorPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

    function tlanPresent() {
      if ( document.getElementById( 'tlanPresentNo' ).checked ) {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonTlanChecks' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'tlanChecksOk' ).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById( 'tlanChecksNok' ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById( 'buttonTlanChecks' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'tlanChecksOk' ).disabled = false;
        document.getElementById( 'tlanChecksNok' ).disabled = false;
      } // close IF
    } // close FUNC
    $( function() { // when page loads
      tlanPresent(); // run FUNC
      // when either radio is clicked, run the function
      $( 'input[ name = "tlanPresent" ]' ).on( "click", tlanPresent );
    }); // close docReady FUNC

  </script>
```

I know its quite bloated and not very efficient, but like I said I am just getting going with JS, so I have lots to learn to improve.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: hi, can you share the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution using Vanilla *(pure)* JS:

```
var form  = document.getElementById("formId");
var allElements = form.elements;
for (var i = 0, l = allElements.length; i < l; ++i) {
    // allElements[i].readOnly = true;
       allElements[i].disabled=true;
}
```

That `for` loop parses all elements inside the form and sets `true` to their `disabled` (or `readOnly`) property to. Which makes everything inside the form *disable*.

---

Here is a fiddle:

```js
var form  = document.getElementById("formId");
var allElements = form.elements;
for (var i = 0, l = allElements.length; i < l; ++i) {
    // allElements[i].readOnly = true; 
       allElements[i].disabled=true;
}
```

```html
<form id="formId">
  <textarea>write sth</textarea><br>
  <input type="text" /><br>
</form>
```

Comment: so this is to toggle elements inside of a form. but I have sections in my form inside divs, and it is only sections of the form id'd by div that i want to be able to disable/enable while keeping the rest of the form unchanged.

Comment: `readOnly` and `disabled` are different.  When a form element is `disabled`, not only is user interaction disabled, but if the form is submitted the disabled elements are not included with the GET or POST parameters.

Comment: So the last line should be replaced with `allElements[i].disabled=true;`. Thanks for the point @Pointy.

Comment: Also, `readOnly` is only applicable on form elements where interaction alters the actual `value` property of the element, such as text fields. Using `readOnly` on a checkbox or radio button won't have any effect and won't prevent the user from toggling them.

Comment: Disabled inputs is fine and even preferable because I want the inputs disabled based on other user input in the form and so for no values for disabled inputs to be updated the DB.

Comment: `var allElements = form.elements; ` is giving me an error.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of null. @Shafizadeh could you point me to a resource to read more about the method?

Comment: @Shafizadeh Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7):

Use this [`document.querySelectorAll('form > *')`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbp5W589jTAhVDsY8KHZ-7ADMQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw) .The will select all the innerElement of the form

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form > *').forEach(function(a){
a.disabled=true;
})
```

```html
<form>
<input>
<input>
<input>
<select></select>
</form>
```

Comment: Careful as the use of '>' will only select direct children of the form element. The input in <form><div><input></div></form> wouldn't be selected afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName("form").disabled = true;`.

Comment: No you can't, because there is no `getElementByTagName()` function. It's `getElementsByTagName()` and it returns a NodeList.

Comment: @Pointy I made the correction. I was typing too fast and omitted the s.

Comment: It still won't work. The return value from that function is not an element — it's a **list** of elements. You have to iterate through the list and disable each one. (There may be only one `<form>` on the page, but you still get a list back.)

Comment: What @Pointy already stated + adding a `disabled` property to a form element does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a loop for get all elements from form then add each one the code bellow:

```
elementFromForm.disabled = true;
```